# Is this DFP error message the reason my ad won't show?

Tags: advertising, google-dfp

I'm setting up DFP to display ads and I have an ad tag (Javascript) from adtechus.com. The tag looks like this:

```
<script src="http://adserver.adtechus.com/?adrawdata/1.0/1111/11111/0/0/ADTECH;loc=100;noperf=1;"></script>
```

When I paste that tag into DFP, I get an error message saying it does't recognize the tag format:

[image]

...and, more importantly, my ad isn't showing on the page. DFP seems to be taking my adtechus ad tag regardless and working with it, despite the error message. But could that be the reason my ad isn't showing? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the ad code/service. You can verify this by doing one or both of these:

**1**: Try inserting a simple .js file that outputs some text, if that works then you know DFP isn't blocking scripts.

**2**: Try inserting your ad code on another site and see if the ad displays. I tried it on jsfiddle and couldn't get it to appear.